# Run java process in windows console from another java process

Tags: java, windows, jar, console, processbuilder

I am trying to start another Java process from my Java process. The problem is that I want Windows console to appear and AnotherApp to write to that console.

This Java snippet does start a new process, **but console does not appear.**

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/k", "java", "-jar", "AnotherApp.jar");
pb.start();
```

If I run from Start - Run

```
cmd /k java -jar AnotherApp.jar
```

then a new console is created and java process is started.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "start", "java", "-jar", "AnotherApp.jar");
```

Comment: `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "start": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)`

Comment: Updated the answer, try this version, please.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative.

```
String cmd[]={"cmd", "/c", "start", "java", "-jar", "AnotherApp.jar"};

Runtime rt=Runtime.getRuntime();

Process p=rt.exec(cmd);
```

you can get output stream of p(that will be given to you as inputstream to read from) and print it to any console.